# Slipstream SP1 into Windows Server 2008 R2 installation files

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, service-pack, windows

Slipstreaming Windows service packs used to be a simple process with earlier versions - just run the EXE with a special command-line switch. I can't seem to find such a switch with  Windows Server 2008 R2 service pack 1. How do I slipstream it? TechNet mentions "integrated installation", so it's possible, but it doesn't seem to have any details on how to actually do it!

Answer (score 8):

It's messy, so it's usually easier to get a copy of Server 2008 R2 w/ SP1.

You can do it manually. [The direction for Win7 are the same](https://superuser.com/questions/249275/slipstream-windows-7-service-pack-1).

Comment: Wow, "messy" is an understatement. Why, Microsoft, why?

Answer (score 2):

Just download it directly:

http://www.shifnet.com/blog/technology/download-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-official-iso-180-days-free-trial.html

Comment: It's sad how you have to side step Microsoft if you were unfortunate enough to have an OEM or Retail license...